# How to get mapped entities from different databases?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, multiple-databases

I have two different (`entity1` and `entity2`) mapped (`@OneToOne` or `@OneToMany`) entities from two different database schemas (`db1` and `db2`).
If I try traditional ways, I got errors that are about "`db1.entity2 does not exist`". Because `entity1` is in `db1` and `entity2` is in `db2`.

I tried to fill all the `entity1` objects with `entity2` objects after `findAll();`. But it takes a lot of time (more than 20 sec.)

Is there any way to map them to each other or fill after in a quick way?

Note: I can not get all the `entity2` data from the database each time. Because there are a lot.
Note 2: I will try to get `entity2` objects I need, with `Native Query` by the list of id.

*I use the last version of Spring Boot JPA Projection, MySQL db, and Java 11.*

Answer (score 0):

You can add schema="db1" for entity1, and schema="db2" for entity2 in JPA annotation or xml mapping.

If there are a lot of entity2 for an entity1, declare the relationship as LAZY. You can use JPQL/Criteria API to get certain entity2(s) instead of native query.

Try Cmobilecom JPA that is small, fast and smart in generating SQL.

Comment: Actually, the problem is not that. I already configured the different databases with the schemas. I need something about business logic.